# Free SQL Server 2005 auto-compete tool

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a free or very inexpensive alternative to SQL Prompt for SQL Server 2005?

Comment: I don't think so.  SSMS 2008 and higher have built-in autocomplete, but it doesn't work with Server 2005.  Gotta agree that SQL Prompt is too expensive if you can't get your employer to pay for it.

Comment: Why the close votes?  The FAQ says "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic... on [the first page](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx) or [SSMS Toolpack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/).